# Python Video is stuttering

Tags: python, video, tkinter

I am trying to make an interactive video and to actually play the video I've got this code: 
*it is code modified from another post on here.

```
def player(canvas):



    b = video.get_next_data()
    frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(b))
    canvas.create_image(600, 400.5, image= frame_image)
    root.after(0.001, player(canvas))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width="1920", height="1080")
    canvas.pack()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=player, args=(canvas,))
    thread.daemon = 60
    thread.start()

    root.mainloop()
```

I am using a canvas as later on I need to add a button that will go over top the video. I also used a while loop and it still stutters.

The video stutters when playing back and I took a look a the task manager and I think it may be stuttering because it is using too much ram. Anyhow could somebody please help with this issue? Any suggestions too would be very appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: There's probably not enough information here to say for sure, but it looks like you are trying to render every frame of video 'by hand' into an image on your canvas from the child thread. That's probably a very inefficient way of doing what you want. You might be better off seeing if TKinter has a native video-playing widget and using that instead.

Comment: instead of createing new `PhotoImage` again and again you could change data in existing `PhotoImage`. `after()` uses time in milliseconds so  for `0.001s` (`1ms`) use `after(1, ...)`. Video with `25 FPS` needs `40ms` for every frame (1000/25)  - `after(40, ...)`. Video with `60FPS` needs about `16ms` for every frame - `after(16, ...)`

Comment: @furas thank you! I'm just a bit confused on how to implement that. I tried `frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage.after(16, Image.fromarray(b))` but it tells me that PhotoImage does not have an `after` attribute. Am I doing something wrong? But thank you for your help!!!

Comment: `after` is `root` method, not `PhotoImage` method and `after()` expects function name without `()` (so called "callback") - `root.after(16, player)`, not `root.after(16, player() )`. If you have to assign function with arguments then you need `lambda` - `root.after(16, lambda:player(canvas) )`

Comment: BTW: `after()` is used to create funtion without `thread` - if you run code in thread then you can use `while loop` with `time.sleep()`

Comment: @furas alright thank you. Sorry I'm quite new to programming so I'm just not sure how you would go about changing the data in the PhotoImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix two different method to work with long-running function.

First using only `after()`

```
def player(canvas):
    b = video.get_next_data()

    frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(b))
    canvas.create_image(600, 400.5, image= frame_image)

    # run it again after 16ms
    root.after(16, lambda:player(canvas))

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width="1920", height="1080")
canvas.pack()

# start player
player(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Second using `threading`

```
def player(canvas):
    while True
        b = video.get_next_data()

        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(b))
        canvas.create_image(600, 400.5, image= frame_image)

        time.sleep(0.16)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width="1920", height="1080")
canvas.pack()

thread = threading.Thread(target=player, args=(canvas,))
thread.daemon = 60
thread.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Because `tkinter` is not thread-safe` so second method may not works sometimes.

---

Other problem - already resolved in code above - `after` expects "callback" - it means function name without `()` and arguments. To use function which needs arguments then you have to use `lambda` to create function without arguments.

```
root.after(16, lambda:player(canvas))
```

---

Last problem - for every video frame you create new `PhotoImage` and new `object on canvas (using`create_image`) so finally you have many objects on canvas (one above another) and many objects in memory.

You would have to create one `PhotoImage` on `Canvas` and replace data in this object.

I can't test it but it could be something like this

```
def player(canvas_image):
    b = video.get_next_data()

    frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(b))

    if canvas_image is None:
        # create first canvas image
        canvas_image = canvas.create_image(600, 400.5, image=frame_image)
    else:
        # replace image in canvas object
        canvas.itemconfig(canvas_image, image=frame_image)

    root.after(16, lambda:player(canvas_image))

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width="1920", height="1080")
canvas.pack()

canvas_image = None

player(canvas_image)

root.mainloop()
```

or using two variables

```
def player(frame_image, canvas_image):
    b = video.get_next_data()


    if canvas_image is None:
        # create first canvas image
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(b))
        canvas_image = canvas.create_image(600, 400.5, image=frame_image)
    else:
        # replace image in canvas object
        frame_image.paste(Image.fromarray(b))
        canvas.itemconfig(canvas_image, image=frame_image)

    root.after(16, lambda:player(frame_image, canvas_image))

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width="1920", height="1080")
canvas.pack()

frame_image = None
canvas_image = None

player(frame_image, canvas_image)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** version with global variables

```
def player(): # without `frame_image`, `canvas_image`
    global frame_image
    global canvas_image

    b = video.get_next_data()

    if canvas_image is None:
        # create first canvas image
        frame_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(b))
        canvas_image = canvas.create_image(600, 400.5, image=frame_image)
    else:
        # replace image in canvas object
        frame_image.paste(Image.fromarray(b))
        canvas.itemconfig(canvas_image, image=frame_image)

    root.after(16, player) # without `frame_image`, `canvas_image`

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width="1920", height="1080")
canvas.pack()

frame_image = None
canvas_image = None

player() # without `frame_image`, `canvas_image`

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! But the problem is that `canvas_image` doesn't have a `.config` attribute. And I tested it earlier and it seems that the video doesn't even play with method 1. It just opens up and sits there without any error messages either.

Comment: My mistake - it has to be `canvas.itemconfig(canvas_image, image=...)` instead of `canvas_image.config(image=...)`. I changed it in code. More about canvas on [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm), [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) and [PIL - ImageTk](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageTk.html), [PIL - Image](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html)

Comment: okay thank you! And using two variables seems to work!!! Thank you so much!!! It is a still slightly slow and stutters a bit. Do you think that is because of my system?

Comment: I don't jave camera to test code and see if it works fast enought. There are other methods like [embeding VLC player in tkinter window](http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/tkvlc.py;h=55314cab09948fc2b7c84f14a76c6d1a7cbba127;hb=HEAD)

Comment: link for GIF: https://imgur.com/a/ccXIU     Anyhow I think that is because of my computer. Thank you for the code!!!

Comment: @Egor.L  To reduce stutter, I would *try* making frame_image and canvas_image into globals, using the code in the player if-block, instead of player parameters.  Player would then simplify to 3 lines and the after call would simplify to `root.after(16, player)`.  But this might not make a visible difference.  Or reduce the frame rate.

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy I'm not quite sure how you would go about setting them as globals because what I've tried kept erroring me. Also do you maybe know how I could loop the video so that it would play non-stop until a button is pressed? But anyhow thank you for your help!

Comment: all variables created outside functions/methods/classes are global - like `frame_image = None` and `canvas_image = None` in my example. To use global variables inside function you have to use `global` inside function - like `global frame_image` and `global canvas_image`.

Comment: I added version with global variables.

Comment: to play till you press button you have to use (global) variable ie. `display = True`  and inside function `if display: root.after(16, player)`. When you set `display = False` (if function assigned to button) then it stops executing `root.after` and it stops displaying new images.

Comment: @furas  thank you so much!!! It works a lot better now and stutters less. Its still there but I think it'll be fine. I think I'll just switch to OpenCV later on because I won't need the buttons. Anyhow thank you for all the help, its very appreciated! Thank you!!!!

Comment: @furas So I've got the button and set it to a function that makes `display = False`. And I've set the `if display == True:` however once the changer function runs the video doesn't stop. I've set `display = True` before as a global variable but it doesn't appear to work. Do you maybe know how to fix that? But I managed to set the function to destroy the canvas widget so maybe I could also get it to run and create another canvas at the same time.

Comment: to change global variable inside function you have to add `global display` inside function. Witthout `global display` code `display = False` creates local variable.